# footer not display in pdf

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to create a pdf with footer.
I tried the following code to have footer in my pdf file.

```
private void AddFooter(string filephysicalpath, string documentname)
        {
            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filephysicalpath);
            Font blackFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
                using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream))
                {
                    int pages = reader.NumberOfPages;

                    for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
                    {
                        string footer = Convert.ToString(Session["Footer"]);
                        footer += "\n";
                        footer += documentname;
                        Phrase ph = new Phrase(footer);
                        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10f, 10f, 0);
                        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(stamper.GetUnderContent(i));
                        ct.SetSimpleColumn(rect);
                        ct.AddElement(new Paragraph("line 1"));
                        ct.AddElement(new Paragraph("line 2"));
                        ct.Go();    
                        // ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetUnderContent(i), Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED, new Phrase(ph), 8f, 5f, 0);
                    }
                }
                bytes = stream.ToArray();
            }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filephysicalpath, bytes);
        }
```

I am not getting the footer with this code.

Comment: Looks ok at first glance, if you use `stamper#GetOverContent(i)`, does the text still not show up?

Comment: This can never work because `new Rectangle(10f, 10f, 0)` can never be a rectangle that fits your text.

Comment: i change code......ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(stamper.GetUnderContent(i));
                        ct.SetSimpleColumn(new Phrase(new Chunk(footer, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12, Font.NORMAL))),
                                           46, 190, 590, 36, 25, Element.ALIGN_LEFT | Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
                        ct.Go();  it give correct output but it override to pdf text how can i solve issue

Comment: How did you determine the coordinates? Why are they hard coded?

Comment: any other solution to add footer with multi line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong for two reasons:

Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10f, 10f, 0);

**Reason #1:**

There is no way this code can work, because you're creating a rectangle with lower-left coordinate `(0, 0)`, upper-right coordinate `(10, 10)` and rotation 0. This is a rectangle that measures 0.14 x 0.14 inch (or 0.35 x 0.35 cm). This can never fit the two lines!

**Reason #2:**

You are using hard coded values to define the `Rectangle`. Please take a look at the documentation, more specifically at the FAQ entry [How to position text relative to page?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-position-text-relative-page)

You have to get the dimensions of the existing page, and define your coordinates accordingly!

```
float marginLR = 36;
float marginB = 2;
float footerHeight = 34;
Rectangle pagesize = reader.GetCropBox(i);
if (pagesize == null) {
    pagesize = reader.GetPageSize(i);
}
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(
    pagesize.Left + marginLR, pagesize.Bottom + margin,
    pagesize.Right - marginLR, pagesize.Bottom + margin + footerheight
);
```

You may also benefit from reading [Get exact cordinates of the page to add a watermark with different page rotation using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798383/)