# How to rotate watermark (text) in PDF using iText?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, watermark

I'm using iText for stamping a watermark (text: "SuperEasy You Done") on PDF files as described in [How to watermark PDFs using text or images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560373/how-to-watermark-pdfs-using-text-or-images/29587148#29587148) ([TransparentWatermark2.java](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs/watermark-examples#1040-transparentwatermark2.java)). [See project source code on GitHub](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/rotate-watermark-with-itext/tree/horizontal).

Now an example of the PDF I'm getting is [this one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7t932sedbr2452x/PDF_FIle_sample.pdf?dl=0) (the rest of the document is omitted):

[image]

As you can see the watermark is centered and horizontal.

I'd like to **keep it centered** in the middle of the page, but **rotate it "45" degrees**, so it rotates anticlockwise. Something like this:

[image]

[This is the code](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/rotate-watermark-with-itext/blob/4d9ade774aeb72c6ca3f23b86c8ee5498b0e6d0f/src/main/java/com/sample/watermark/service/AppService.java#L82) for stamping the watermark on a given byte array (pdf documents only for me right now)

```
/**
 * Returns the same document with the watermark stamped on it.
 * @param documentBytes Byte array of the pdf which is going to be returned with the watermark
 * @return byte[] with the same byte array provided but now with the watermark stamped on it.
 * @throws IOException If any IO exception occurs while adding the watermark
 * @throws DocumentException If any DocumentException exception occurs while adding the watermark
 */
private byte[] getDocumentWithWaterMark(byte[] documentBytes) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // pdf
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(documentBytes);
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputStream);
    // text watermark
    Font font = new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 60);
    Phrase phrase = new Phrase("SuperEasy You Done", font);
    // transparency
    PdfGState gs1 = new PdfGState();
    gs1.setFillOpacity(0.06f);
    // properties
    PdfContentByte over;
    Rectangle pagesize;
    float x, y;
    // loop over every page (in case more than one page)
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        pagesize = reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(i);
        x = (pagesize.getLeft() + pagesize.getRight()) / 2;
        y = (pagesize.getTop() + pagesize.getBottom()) / 2;
        over = stamper.getOverContent(i);
        over.saveState();
        over.setGState(gs1);
        // add text
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(over, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, phrase, x, y, 0);
        over.restoreState();
    }
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

PS: I read this, but it didn't help:

- http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/rotate-a-watermark-td2155042.html

Comment: https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-watermark-pdfs-using-text-or-images

Comment: @Sedrick Thank for the link. Could you point me on the right direction... where specifically in that post is explained what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I didn't take a deep look. I saw that they showed how to rotate 90 degrees. I assume one could use that method to make the rotation > or < 90 degrees

Comment: @Sedrick in the post you linked this is the line where they apply it `over.addImage(img, w, 0, 0, h, x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2));`. The thing is they don't say that explicitly, it is only mentioned _...the appropriate parameters for the transformation matrix..._ Anyways, I [found it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52765615/5640649) the hard way (reading a lot :D ). Thanks.

Comment: Hello, what is the dependency you used for adding watermark.

Comment: @RealTechHacks this one: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext ... But notice, this one was moved to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf   ... you can see the full list of the example project I posted here: https://github.com/lealceldeiro/rotate-watermark-with-itext/blob/horizontal/pom.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to specify the desired rotation angle as the 6th parameter in [this line](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/rotate-watermark-with-itext/blob/4d9ade774aeb72c6ca3f23b86c8ee5498b0e6d0f/src/main/java/com/sample/watermark/service/AppService.java#L107):

```
ColumnText.showTextAligned(over, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, phrase, x, y, 0); // rotate 0 grades in this case
```

If the specified value is positive ( > 0) the rotation is anticlockwise, otherwise (< 0) the rotation is clockwise.

In this particular case, for rotating the watermark 45 degrees anticlockwise you just need to write the previous line [like this](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/rotate-watermark-with-itext/blob/ede1acfe5e862882c1bd2f85d2838264c4cf7d13/src/main/java/com/sample/watermark/service/AppService.java#L107):

```
ColumnText.showTextAligned(over, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, phrase, x, y, 45f); // 45f means rotate the watermark 45 degrees anticlockwise
```

By applying this same principle we can achieve any rotation in any direction.

---

The whole documentation is here: https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/api-documentation under the links for [version 5](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText5/java/5.5.13.2/) and [version 7](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.2.1/).

Comment: @gpasch yeah! you're right. I'm new to iText, so I'm kind of learning and just discovered the documentation https://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/ (v5)

Comment: in iText v7, put 120 in param radAngle to make it 45 degree diagonal.